# Check nil values in .map method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When `User` object is nil, which is defined in belongs_to association, I get an error: `p.user.title` is `nil`.

How to check that `p.user` or `p.user.title` is defined in .map to avoid an error?

```
@posts = Post.all 
results = @posts.map { |p| 
{ 
  :id => p.id,
  :text => p.text,
  :user_title => p.user.title
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `try` method.  This will return `nil` if the user is `nil`

```
@posts = Post.all 
results = @posts.map { |p| 
    { 
      :id => p.id,
      :text => p.text,
      :user_title => p.user.try(:title)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy as pie.

```
p.user.try(:title)
```

The above runs #title on user if user is not nil.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for giving points to other guy - both answers are the same, so I selected it by time of the answer. Only few seconds less :))

Comment: Well, to be fair I had the earlier time. :P But I too noticed that the answer came in just after I had posted, so I can't say I blame ya.

Answer (score 1):

Simple - just test `p.user` before you access `title`:

```
@posts = Post.all 
results = @posts.map do |p| 
  { 
    :id => p.id,
    :text => p.text,
    :user_title => p.user && p.user.title
  }
end
```

`results[i][:user_title]` will then be `nil` if either `p.user` or `p.user.title` was.